# Problemas con el navegador mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Tengo un problema; Tengo un método para generar un excel a partir de una tabla y funciona pero en Google Chrome, sin embargo voy a probar en mozilla  y no funciona...

Alguna sugerencia??

## CODIGO

```
<title>Reportes Equipo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Librerias para Exportar excel--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/exportarExcel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <!--Librerias para datepicker-->            
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="JS/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

La estructura de la tabla es basica;
Y con este `botton` creo el excel.

```
 <input type='submit'  value="EXPORTAR" style='background:url("IMG/excel.png") no-repeat; padding-left: 30px ; height: 30px' id="btnExport" />
```

Por ultimo esta es la parte de que crea el excel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();

         // calculamos la fecha actual 
          var hoy = new Date();
          dia = hoy.getDate(); 
          mes = hoy.getMonth() + 1 ;
          anio= hoy.getFullYear();
          fecha_actual = String(dia + "_" + mes + "_" + anio);

         // Pagina que hizo el llamado 
        var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;

         //Obtenemos los valores de la tabla 
         var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
         var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper');
         var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

         var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
         a.download = 'Reporte ' + pagina + ' '+ fecha_actual + '.xls';
         a.click();
     });
});
```

No me genera ningún error, solo no crea el excel .

Alguna solución ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de leer mucho en diferentes foros no encontré solución a mi problema, al parecer mozilla-Firefox no es compatible, por lo cual es necesario utilizar otra función como esta:

```
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#table_wrapper').html()));
          e.preventDefault();
```

El problema con esta solución es que el nombre del archivo es estático  y al utilizar `encodeURIComponent` El nombre del archivo sera incomprensible.

Sin embargo la información se conserva  muy bien (SIEMPRE QUE NO UTILICES CARACTERES ESPECIALES-> ES MI CASO)

Lastimosamente no encontré mas soluciones que colocar los 2 métodos  y recomendar la utilización de Google Chroom para la realización de informes.

Mi código quedo algo así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
        var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

        if (es_firefox ) {
          window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#table_wrapper').html()));
          e.preventDefault();
        }else{
         var a = document.createElement('a');  

         // calculamos la fecha actual 
          var hoy = new Date();
          dia = hoy.getDate(); 
          mes = hoy.getMonth() + 1 ;
          anio= hoy.getFullYear();
          fecha_actual = String(dia + "_" + mes + "_" + anio);

         // Pagina que hizo el llamado 
        var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;

         //Obtenemos los valores de la tabla 
         var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
         var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper');
         var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');


         a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
         a.download = 'Reporte ' + pagina + ' '+ fecha_actual + '.xls';
         a.click();

         e.preventDefault();  
        }

     });
});
```

Lo que hago es que valido que navegador esta utilizando y utilizo la función  necesaria..

Espero ayudar a alguien con mi caso (y)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `a.click()` no inicia el download en Mozilla. Deberías poner el `a` recién creado en la página con una leyenda que diga "excel generado, descargar aquí" o algo así.

También coniene reemplazar

```
var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

por

```
var table_html = table_div.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarme un ejemplo lo he intentado de diferentes maneras, y sigue sin funcionar  @Emilio Platzer